# Swift: Printing without alert box

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I use the following codes for printing in the app:

```
    init() {
    self.printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.photo
    self.printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.landscape
    self.printController.printInfo = self.printInfo
    self.printer = UIPrinter(url: URL(string: printIP)!)
    // where printIP is a string that give the internal IP of the printer
    debugPrint(printIP)
  }



  func print(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    self.printController.printingItem = image
    printController.print(to: printer, completionHandler: {(controller, success, error) -> Void in
      if success {
        debugPrint("Printing Completed.")
      } else {
        debugPrint("Printing Failed.")
      }
    })
    return true
  }
```

It can print successfully. However, when the function is triggered, there is an alert box indicating that it is contacting to the Printer, and printing. Is there any method to avoid the pop up of this alert box? I want the printing done at the back without showing anything on the screen that interfere the user experience (I want to play a movie when the printer is working at the back).

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find solution for this? i want to do same or my iOS app in Objective-C, want to print without alertbox. Please help me if you found somehting.

Answer (score 3):

> From iOS 8 there is a way to print without any presentation of the
>   printing UI. Instead of presenting the UI each time the user presses a
>   print button, you can provide a way for your users to select a printer
>   somewhere in your app with the easy-to-use UIPrinterPickerController.
>   It accepts an optional UIPrinter instance in its constructor for a
>   pre-selection, uses the same presentation options as explained above,
>   and has a completion handler for when the user has selected her
>   printer:

---

Swift 3

```
let printerPicker = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: savedPrinter)
printerPicker.present(animated: true) {
    (printerPicker, userDidSelect, error) in

    if userDidSelect {
        self.savedPrinter = printerPicker.selectedPrinter
    }
}
```

---

Now you can tell your UIPrintInteractionController to print directly by calling printToPrinter(:completionHandler:) with the saved printer instead of using one of the present... methods.

Source:- http://nshipster.com/uiprintinteractioncontroller/

Comment: My code already asked the printer to print directly without pop up the printing UI. What I concern is the pop up of an alert box that allow user to cancel the printing service (when it is contacting the printer, or showing other status).

Comment: I am already using the printToPrinter method as you can see in my code.